# How to stop the Month and Day from changing in the BindingSource.Filter?

Tags: vb.net, date, filter, bindingsource

This is the code for my BindingSource.Filter

```
 Dim FilterStartMonth As Date = DateTimePickerTodaysDateTime.Value.Date
 Dim Filter2MonthsBack As Date = DateTimePickerTodaysDateTime.Value.AddMonths(-2).Date
 ClockInTimesBindingSource.Filter = "EmployeeID = " & ComboBoxOfficeEmployeeFilter.SelectedValue & " and Date <= '" & Filter2MonthsBack & "' and Date >= '" & FilterStartMonth & "'"
```

When i go through it step by step as it runs these are the values:

Filter2MonthsBack = 1/2/2017 12:00:00 AM

FilterStartMonth = 3/2/2017 12:00:00 AM

Which is how i want them, but the BindingSource.Filter reads:

ClockInTimesBindingSource.Filter = "EmployeeID = 49 and Date <= '02/01/2017' and Date >= '02/03/2017'"

I can't work out why it is swapping the month and day around??

Any help would be much appreciated.

I have tried using .ToString("d") but it still chnges around in the filter  string.

Comment: It might very well not be changing them.  One could be M/d/y and the other d/M/y since you are in the UK - VS will show dates in Invariant `M/d/y` format.  What datatype is `Date` in the datasource?

Comment: I would like to store them as dd/MM/yyyy but i couldn't find a way to store them like that in my `DataTable`, the closest `DataType` i found was "d" which is MM/dd/yyyy. If i could store dates as dd/MM/yyyy that would save me alot of hassle.

Comment: Well if you are string them in any format at all, you are not storing dates, but strings because dates do not have a format.  **What datatype is `Date` in the datasource?**

Comment: It is `DataType` "d"

Comment: @Plutonix Clear as mud now?

Comment: Ok, start from the beginning.  I assume this involves a DataBase?  If so which DB?  And what is the datatype *there* - there is no 'd' type for any DB I am aware of.

Comment: Yes it's from a SQL DB and the DataType is DateTime.

Comment: Then all should be well, just banish from your mind the idea you need to format any date ever.  Without regard to what the filter text looks like, does the query show the results for the correct month?

Comment: It comes back with no results, which is why i thought the format mattered.

Comment: That tells us nothing because for all we know there are no records in that range.  Wait - that filter setter is wrong - you are forcing the dates to string.

Comment: I have filled the db with dates for the whole year, i can assure you the dates are there :) but yes there must be something wrong with the filter, i think the way it is written formats the dates as a string maybe? I know with different " ' and the end it's thinks it's a double?

Comment: You have a field named "Date"?  Ugh.  Never do that.  Try putting brackets around that `[Date]` since date is a keyword and that *might* be interfering with the filter.

Comment: @LarsTech a very good point i hadn't thought of but now you mention it. I will change that.

Edit : I have now changed the column to ClockDate but still no results but i will remember that in future thank you.

Comment: We do not live inside your computer so we cant know what data is there and what is missing.  Hence `for all we know...`

Comment: I know that, i was being polite when i said i said assure you it's there. Sorry if it was taken the wrong way.

Comment: Your query says, filter where the date is <= Jan 2, 2017 AND date is >= Mar 2, 2017.  Query works, since that isn't possible.

Comment: Oh my days, So i changed it to  >= Jan 2, 2017 AND date is <= Mar 2, 2017 and it works!  Thank you but my word how did i not see that.

I thought it read greater than or equal to Jan 2 and Less than or equal to Mar 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query says:

> filter where the date is <= Jan 2, 2017 AND date is >= Mar 2, 2017

Query works, since that isn't possible.

You probably meant to switch the equation around:

```
" and Date >= '" & Filter2MonthsBack & "' and Date <= '" & FilterStartMonth & "'"
```